# Hyperlinking multiple columns to the same cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hyperlink Cells C to I from Rows 4 to 14 which all contains values to another sheet with a singular column in A that contains values.

I want the values to match and be hyperlinked, e.g I click on Cell C4 and it links me directly to the other sheet and to the direct cell.

Is there any way to do this?

Have tried using this VBA Code:

```
Sub AddHyperlinks2()
Dim i As Long, Lr1 As Long, Lr2 As Long, Cr As Long, CrA As String
Lr1 = Sheets("APRILZ").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Lr2 = Sheets("DATABASE").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
On Error GoTo NextC
 For i = 2 To Lr1
On Error GoTo NextC
    Cr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C" & i).Value, Sheets("DATABASE").Range("D1:D" & Lr2), 0)
    CrA = Range("D" & Cr).Address
    Sheets("APRILZ").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("APRILZ").Range("C" & i), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & Sheets("DATABASE").Name & "'!" & CrA, TextToDisplay:=Sheets("DATABASE").Range("D" & i).Value
NextC:
Resume NextD
NextD:
Next i
End Sub
```

But it only hyperlinks the first cell C4 in this case as the other cells have repeated values

Comment: Screenshots of your data and hyperlink destinations might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need without the  need for run-time error handling:

```vb
Sub AddHyperlinks2()
    
    Dim rngMatch As Range, c As Range, wsApr As Worksheet, m, v
    
    With Sheets("DATABASE")
        Set rngMatch = .Range("D1:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row)
    End With
    
    Set wsApr = Sheets("APRILZ")
    
    For Each c In wsApr.Range("C2:C" & wsApr.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row).Cells
        v = c.Value
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
            m = Application.Match(c.Value, rngMatch, 0) 'no Worksheetfunction = no run-time error
            If Not IsError(m) Then                      'test for a match
                wsApr.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", _
                  SubAddress:=rngMatch.Cells(m).Address(True, True, external:=True), _
                  TextToDisplay:=c.Value
            End If
        End If 'any cell value
    Next c
    
End Sub
```